# Automatically copying PHP files to WWW directory

Tags: php

While developing PHP projects, I need to continuously copy the files from my project folder to  WWW folder of my local web server for testing. I do know that NetBeans supports doing this automatically, but it's not the IDE I use all the time.

So, is there a small tool or script already made that will help me with this? I need to be able to execute a command on the shell that'd copy preconfigured files to a preconfigured location. I'm using Windows, by the way.

**EDIT:** I think [Phing](http://www.phing.info/trac/) is what I'm looking for.

Comment: have you considered `file_get_contents()` / `file_put_contents()`?

Comment: seems like you'd better use svn or something like this

Comment: I think [Phing](http://www.phing.info/trac/) is what I'm looking for. I'll check it out and see if it works as I want.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using windows then just make a .bat file that does this magic. Will be clean and fast.

But yes, SVN would be the best for this. Just commit localy and update on the server.

Comment: SVN? GIT would be better. And use a post-receive hook.

Comment: SVN or GIT is a matter of choice. I meant just a version control software. No matter witch one.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. If your are familiar with basic Linux commands, Cygwin would be a perfect option for you:
http://cygwin.com/
(cron, cp, scp, rsync a lot more useful things)

However, the most simple solution would be writing a windows batch script, like this:
http://theos.in/news/windows-xp-batch-file-script-to-copy-all-files/
(it doesn't require any installation at all)

Answer (score 0):

create a shell script like this

in windows

```
 xcopy "test.php" "..\..\..\Path\to\save" /s /i /c /y
 xcopy "*.php" "..\..\..\Path\to\save" /s /i /c /y
```

linux

```
cp test.php /dir
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you place your IDE workspace in the www folder?

Answer (score 0):

What I've found useful in the past is this:

- put the code on your development PC, and share it
- mount the share on the server PC using Samba

This allows you the best of both worlds - editing is nice and fast, and you can test it very quickly. You will not notice the performance hit caused by the Samba link (and in fact, having a development environment run ludicrously fast can be deceptive!)

If you work in a team, there are other benefits in that you can share the same server setup, which is handy if you're using a large database or exotic setups.